# Find and replace file names to C standard

Tags: python, bash, parsing

I have a project shared by a friend which includes headers that have case conflicts (eg: #include `"xyz.h"` but the actual file is `Xyx.h`).

How should I solve this? 
 I decided to write a python or bash script to parse all the `#include`'s and then search if they are actually in the directory. Is this a good approach? 
Which one should I use, python or bash. I think bash would be easier because it can handle files and replace names easier. But will I have to write regular expressions in my bash script?

Comment: Who is responsible for the case conflicts, you or your friend?  If your friend, then ask him/her to make the correction ;).  The tool you use is a matter of preference.  Are the differences ALWAYS in the case of the first letter, or could you have something more esoteric like: #include "whatamess.h" with actual file being "WhAtAmEsS.h"?

Comment: @tnknepp My friend. But it compiles on his PC (I've checked and seen there are case conflicts but his code gets compiled, using STM system workbench on Eclipse - arm-gcc, openOCD). The difference isn't always in the first letter it can be "WhAtAmEsS.h" too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One single bullet proof solution:

- choose a name convention - all lower case is probably the most common one
- rename all include files to their lower case equivalent - do nothing if they are already lower case
- consistently check all source files and ensure that they actually include the lower case name - this should be done by hand because you do not want to process a litteral string containing `#include`

That being said, if the number of files is small, and if files are not too complex, this can possibly be automated. But my opinion is that the gain of time is not worth the development of a tool and the risk of error in it.

Comment: If a script can be made to verify C coding standard and be run before `git push` as a hook it could be used by many other. I was going for this.

Comment: @ClamentJohn: It could be done, but I advise you against it. In order to be used in a general context, it will have to actually parse the C source because according to the C standard, include can happen almost anywhere in the file and not only at its beginning. Clang comes with a parsing library that could help here, but even with that help, it is still far from obvious. What about `#if` blocs, and comments or string litterals sharing multiple lines? What about files from other libraries that could have mixed case names?

Comment: Yes, I understand why it could cause many problems in the future, thanks. Can you suggest a git hook to check C coding standard? What do embedded and other C developers do to keep the project in "the company'" standard

Comment: @ClamentJohn: *If it cannot compile, it is rejected* is the first rule. That is enough when compiling on a case sensitive system. Then there are plenty of tools to ensure some standards (just google for *C code quality analysis*). Finally, peer review is often useful.

Answer (score 1):

This may be less challenging that I initially thought.

```
from glob import glob as gg

# read in list of .h files and build dictionary
hfiles = dict([(r, r.lower) for r in gg('srcDir/*.h')])

# read in c file
with open('srcDir/cfile.c', 'r') as tmp: 
    cfile = tmp.read().split('\n')

# make include replacements (assuming NO text in file prior to include statments...adjust as needed)
for r in arange(len(cfile):
    if ('# include' in cfile[r]) and (cfile[r].split()[-1] in hfiles):
        key = cfile[r].split()[-1].lower()
        cfile[r] = '# include ' + hfiles[key]

# now right out corrected c file
with open('dst/new_c_file.c', 'w') as fid:
    fid.write('\n'.join(cfile))
```

It's not the prettiest code, and I have not tested it (better to NOT overwrite your files until you have tested this), but the general method should work and be quite flexible.