# Eclipse System-Workbench (Win 10 v4.6.3) ignores case when including .h files

Tags: c, eclipse, compiler-errors, eclipse-plugin

In reference to SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50739241/find-and-replace-file-names-to-c-standard) 
My friend's code gets compiled on his Windows PC but it doesn't for my Linux PC. 
I'm using `Eclipse Luna (4.4.2)`, `System Workbench` for STM32-OpenOCD `Version: 1.13.2.201703061529`, arm-none-eabi-gcc version 4.9.3
And he's using `Eclipse v4.6.3`, and SW-STM32 `v1.15.0.201708311556`, arm-none-eabi-gcc v4.7.2.

Forget about versions, a C code is case sensitive to includes and his compiler just outright ignores that!

Anyone have any clue if a flag has been set along with his compiler? Shouldn't we remove this to be on par with the C standard?

Comment: This is not a matter of compiler flags or Eclipse version. The compiler sees a file name and tries to open it.  While C is case sensitive, Windows file systems are not. When the compiler tries to include the file that was specified, the OS will search for it and finally succeed. With identical case or not. For the compiler this is not visible.

Comment: Thank you. So sticking to a format that works for both OSs would be the best option.

Comment: @Gerhardh will windows support "/" or "\"?

Comment: I haven't used Windows compilers for a while. AFAIR MSVC is tolerant regarding path delimiters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this as stated by @Gerhardh is the difference in how the OS searches for files. Windows is not case sensitive whereas Linux is. Sticking to a coding standard is the best option.

Thank you Gerhardh